# Reading debug register produces: "unsupported instruction mov"

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, mov

I am trying to read debug registers on Linux, but I get an `unsupported instruction mov` error, when compiling my inline assembler code with gcc. My code is:

```
asm __volatile__ (
  "movl %eax, %dr0\n"
  );
```

Reading other registers such as esp works fine.

Comment: src on left, dst on right in at&t syntax (your code would be writing to the register not reading it). The code is 32-bit, won't compile with 64-bit. But beyond that you really should look at [extended assembler templates](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) in GCC because you are going to have to properly get the value returned from a register and placed into an appropriate variable without clobbering anything. This is of course if you are mixing _C_ and assembly.

Comment: Also note that the debug registers are privileged so you can't access them directly from user mode.

Comment: Thank you. Managed to solve the problem by adjusting it to 64bit and proper src/dst selection